# How to fix icon on the "running apps" screen?

Tags: android, icons

Everything is okay on the main screen.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjpyg.jpg)

But something goes wrong in the "running apps" screen.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ykpt.jpg)

I tried to change both android:icon and android:logo but that didn't work.

Comment: That didn't help.

Comment: Check for any custom drawable file used in your project. Also search your project with keyword 'ic_launcher' and verify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Set the icon.
       android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
       android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
2. If it doesn't work, try to reboot your phone.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this to your manifest:

```
 android:roundIcon="@mipmap/your_icon_image"
```